# ¿Como puedo leer los valores de entrada del puerto serie?

Tags: c#, .net, puertos, io

Estoy intentando leer los valores de entrada del puerto `com`, en especifico el `COM3`, pero este no funciona.

Probé con los ejemplos que proporciona la pagina de MS, sobre los puertos, pero estas simplemente no reciben datos..

He probado varios códigos, y demos, pero ninguno parece recibir los datos:
1.- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8605/Serial-Communication-using-C-and-Whidbey
2.- https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx#Ejemplos

Estos son algunos ejemplos, que me he basado, y veo que la mayoría utiliza el evento de  `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);`....

He probado con emuladores, que comunican por ejemplo `com1` al `com2`. y estos si funcionan. pero ya recibir los datos del `com3`, no.

Alguien que haya manejado o resuelto esto?

**Editado**

Estoy conectado a una bascula digital, que utiliza el puerto COM3
La imagen que estoy agregando son los parametros que requieren para la conexion en hyperterminal. basicamente esos se los configure manualmente al componente de "SerialPort".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace lectura
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            mySerialPort.Open();

            /*
            while (true) {
                if (mySerialPort.BytesToRead > 0) {
                    byte b = (byte)mySerialPort.ReadByte();
                    Console.WriteLine(b);
                }
            }*/




            //byte b = (byte)mySerialPort.ReadByte();
            //char c = (char)mySerialPort.ReadChar();
            //string line = mySerialPort.ReadLine();

            //
            //Console.WriteLine("byte "+ b);
            //Console.WriteLine("char " + c);
            //Console.WriteLine("line " + line);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
            mySerialPort.Close();
        }
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            print(indata);
            //Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
           // Console.Write(indata);
        }

        private static void print(string data) {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
}
```

y este es el ejemplo que proporciona en la pagina de ms sobre la lectura de los puertos "System.IO.Ports".
Saludos

Comment: Puede ser que no tengas bien configurado tu `COM3`? Exactamente que dispositivo tienes conectado ahí?  es un dispositivo físico o virtual? Pulsa en [edit] y agrega toda la información relevante, ya que tal como está ahora la pregunta es complicado que puedas recibir ayuda...

Comment: @Pikoh es una bascula digital, que al conectarlo me indica que esta en el puerto com3, pero simplemente no llega ningun valor en esta. al tratar de leer los valores

Comment: Es muy dificil que podamos ayudarte con esto, ya que no tenemos suficientes datos.Por un lado no indicas si te da algun error o simplemente no recibes datos. Por el otro, debes asegurarte de que los datos de conexion (baudios,parida...) sean los requeridos. Tambien asegurate de que no haya ninguna otra aplicación que esté haciendo uso de ese puerto.

Comment: @Pikoh ya actualize la pregunta, he probado varios codigos para que funcione. y demos. en si tengo conectado el dispositivo para que la aplicacion pueda reconocer que existe el puerto COM3, ya que prove con emuladores, y estas si funcionan.

Comment: o sea, descartamos que el COM3 anda en la pc, la bascula le manda informacion a algun programa propio u otra cosa?

Comment: @gbianchi en si, estoy tratando de leer los datos que se reciben de la bascula, en form de .net, de hecho el evento DataReceivedHandler, no entra en ningun momento cuando estoy debugg. claro, el ejemplo esta en una aplicacion de consola.

Comment: Si no entra es pq no esta recibiendo datos. puede ser que necesites decirle a la bascula que empieze a mandar? por eso preguntaba si la bascula anda mas alla del programa (o sea si hay forma de probar que manda informacion por ese puerto)}

Comment: @gbianchi con el hyperterminal, puebo que funcione, de hecho si recibe los datos en el hyperTerminal.

Comment: Has probado a poner a false `RTSEnable` y `DTSEnable` por si acaso?

Comment: @gbianchi ya puse esas propiedades en true, de igual manera con  Handshake.None y nada, simplemente el evento de handled no es disparado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí un tutorial como hacerlo, tanto enviar como recibir datos al puerto serie.
https://www.slideshare.net/Metaconta/arduino-consola-y-puerto-serie

Saludos.

Comment: Para que tu respuesta tenga mayor posibilidades de ser aceptada pon un ejemplo

Comment: Ok. Gracias por el aviso.